# How to get the value of a Theano.tensor variable?

Tags: python, theano, tensor

I have to do something like this:

```
import Theano.tensor as tt

a = 2
b = 3
c = tt.arctan2(a,b)
```

c has now as output `Elemwise{arctan2,no_inplace}.0`. How can I get the computed value of the function? Have already read here that I need to compile the Theano function, but didn't really understood how... Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theano you first need to define your variables as symbols. Then you define a function with those symbols. A theano.function has a List of input parameters and the function which should be executed as parameters.

Once that is done, you can compute your function by substituting the symbols with actual values.

```
from theano import function
import theano.tensor as tt

a = tt.dscalar('a')
b = tt.dscalar('b')
f = theano.function([a,b], tt.arctan2(a, b))
f(2, 3)
```

This will output:

```
array(0.5880026)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That's the kind of answer I was looking for! Thanks and have a nice day!